# Algorithmic Puzzle About Using Two Rectangles To Enclose Points

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, puzzle

I've been working on this problem for two days, and the best I can do is a brute force solution which is not efficient enough.

You are given a bunch of positive coordinate points ranging from `(0, 0)` to `(1 billion, 1 billion)`. You must enclose all of the points with only two rectangles with the smallest possible total area. Rectangles must have sides parallel to the x-axis and y-axis. The rectangles **cannot overlap**, sharing the same boundary counts as overlapping. You `**can**` have a `0` by `0` rectangle of area zero. The sum of the areas of the two rectangles is `**X**`

You also have to find a single rectangle of the smallest possible area that encloses all of the points. This area is `**Y**`

You are trying to find `**Y** - **X**`.

For the following example, the answer `**Y** - **X** = 107`.

```
(4, 2), (8, 10), (1, 1), (9, 12), (14, 7), (2, 3)
```

Providing code would be very appreciated, if you do then please use Java or C++ if possible.

Comment: I hope that the people upvoting this understand the puzzle. Because I know I don't. Maybe a diagram of the solution to your example would explain it a bit better.

Comment: You have a bunch of points. You use two rectangles of smallest possible total area to enclose all of the points. What is this area?

Is that clear enough? I'm not sure how a diagram would help

Comment: Finding solution giving the "smallest possible area" is probably what I was missing in your description.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably make that more clear

Comment: So, maximize **Y-X**?  Integral coordinates only?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "brute force"? Does not seem like that hard problem. Just enclose in one rectangle and then try to slice it from all four sides one point by one... the complexity would be < O(N^2).

Comment: Yes. In other words, maximize the difference between the minimum possible areas

Comment: @PavelHoral O(N) is too slow because N could be 1 billion

Comment: (Note that I've corrected the comment - you would need to sort the set of points, which is N*log(N)) ... I would say that lower than O(N) is logical nonsense...

Comment: I would say you can rigorously *prove* less than O(n) is nonsense: Say you have a collection of n points. You only look at the first `n-1` of them to solve your problem. In general, the solution will not involve rectangles that encompass the entire grid (ex: your posted example). So the `n`th point could be outside of the rectangles involved in your solution, thus invalidating it.

Comment: Would a solution that iterates the full list of points twice be acceptable?

Comment: Although I assume that "1 billion" referred to the maximum *coordinates* of the points, and not to the *number* of points, I guess the goal is to find a solution that is polynomial in the number of points.   First I thought that one might abuse [Summed Area Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table), but this doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 4):

I do not want to spoil the game.

Start with the large rectangle. Then you can split on every x or y of a point.

Sort the points once by x, once by y.

Split vertically:

```
#######
#######

   #######
   #######
```

Split horizonally:

```
##
##    ####
      ####
      ####
```

Splitting at a coordinate yields two sets of point where both rectangle halves are easily reduced.

---

***Added a solution because of comment***

As Point class I actually use `int[2]` so the x/y choice can be made as for-index. On the other hand, I had to make a class AreaCollector, where a simple Rectangle would suffice.

The rectangle points I have collected too; without them the code would become a bit smaller.

```
static private class AreaCollector {

    private final int[] lwb = new int[] { Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE };
    private final int[] upb = new int[] { Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE };

    public void add(int[] point) {
        if (point[0] < lwb[0]) {
            lwb[0] = point[0];
        }
        if (point[1] < lwb[1]) {
            lwb[1] = point[1];
        }
        if (point[0] > upb[0]) {
            upb[0] = point[0];
        }
        if (point[1] > upb[1]) {
            upb[1] = point[1];
        }
    }

    public int getArea() {
        if (upb[0] == Integer.MIN_VALUE) { /// Zero points added.
            return 0;
        }
        return (upb[0] - lwb[0]) * (upb[1] - lwb[1]);
    }
}

public int solve(int[][] points) {
    AreaCollector ac = new AreaCollector();
    for (int[] point : points) {
        ac.add(point);
    }
    final int y = ac.getArea();
    final int n = points.length;

    // Best solution sofar:
    int[][] ascPoints = Arrays.copyOf(points, n);
    int[][] descPoints = new int[0][];
    int bestX = y + 0;

    for (int direction = 0; direction < 2; ++direction) {
        final int dir = direction;
        Arrays.sort(points, Comparator.comparingInt((pt) -> pt[dir]));

        int[] ascAreas = new int[n];
        AreaCollector ascAC = new AreaCollector();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {
            int[] point = points[i];
            int coord = point[direction];
            for (int j = i; j < n && points[j][direction] == coord; ++j) {
                ascAC.add(points[j]);
            }
            int area = ascAC.getArea();
            for (int j = i; j < n && points[j][direction] == coord; ++j) {
                ascAreas[j] = area;
                ++i;
            }
        }

        int[] descAreas = new int[n];
        AreaCollector descAC = new AreaCollector();
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; ) {
            int[] point = points[i];
            int coord = point[direction];
            for (int j = i; j >= 0 && points[j][direction] == coord; --j) {
                descAC.add(points[j]);
            }
            int area = descAC.getArea();
            for (int j = i; j >= 0 && points[j][direction] == coord; --j) {
                descAreas[j] = area;
                --i;
            }
        }

        int bestI = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n- 1; ++i) {
            if (points[i][direction] != points[i + 1][direction]) {
                int x = ascAreas[i] + descAreas[i + 1];
                if (x < bestX) {
                    bestX = x;
                    bestI = i;
                }
            }
        }
        if (bestI != -1) {
            ascPoints = Arrays.copyOfRange(points, 0, bestI + 1);
            descPoints = Arrays.copyOfRange(points, bestI + 1, n);
        }
    }
    return y -bestX;
}
```

As Comparator I used java 8 terse notation. As you see the complexity of the hand-coded part is O(N) superseeded by `Arrays.sort` O(N.log N).

Comment: Actually thought about how to implement this and there are few non-trivial issues, which is probably the reason why OP is having problem with it. Some clever lookup strategies to calculate the actual area effectively is still needed (e.g. by having the set of points as two sorted collections - one by X axis and the other one by Y and using them both).

Comment: @PavelHoral yes, there is still some intelligence needed. Personally I would do it differently, make an outline path (of the points at the outer side) and try to split that, A bit more data/algorithmic intelligence needed. Probably a nice solution is feasible.

Comment: The Algorithm for sorting would fit best category called Divide & Conquer paradigm in a similar fashion to the MergeSort algorithm with running time O(n log n) time complexity, We have used a Point2D class, implemented in the edu.princeton.cs.algs4 library (see
link: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/Point2D.java.html )

Comment: This suggests that the solution is simple. Consider a grid where all 9 points from (0,0) to (3,3) are present. You won't get far with sorting these. Moreover, having the points split does not tell you anything about the *area* that the rectangles covering the subsets have. "Not spoiling" may be OK (I don't want to argue about whether stackoverflow is a "question and answer" site, or a "question and vague hint" site...), but I don't see how this answer could be helpful at all...

Comment: @Marco13 answers to real problems should be real too. Homework should *not* be given a full solution. And pure training as here, should be given a push on a feasible track imho.

Comment: @Marco13  In your example one would have 3 x's and 3 y's to split on, giving 6 cases. For N points at most 1+N cases. For say a horizontal split one has to walk both ascending and descending once through all points to determine left and right rectangle, stored in an array. And then once for the sum of areas of each pair of right and left. That is O(N) - if done smartly that is. Writing that would indeed spoil the fun, and I think on writing the solution Bob would find that out too, because it is the laziest way.

Comment: The sorting alone will be O(nlogn) (but I'm pretty sure there is no way to avoid that). One of several crucial points for me was to find, for a given splitting coordinate, the points that are "left" or "right" of that coordinate. While it's technically trivial once they are sorted, you still have to iterate over all "left" and "right" points, once for each splitting coordinate, to obtain the area - and this would be O(n^2), as far as I see. I don't see a simple way of computing an O(1) "lookup" of "splitting coordinate -> (leftArea, rightArea)". But maybe I overlooked some neat trick here.

Comment: No O(N) (+O(n.log n))) as you can start with an empty rectangle and for every next x coordinate add the points at that point to the rectangle: and store that area in an array. One loop for the ascending x, and the same for descending x. That would be O(n), at the space cost of two arrays of n. Adding a point only increases the rect.

Comment: @Marco13 I have given a full answer, because you were principally right about not giving a full answer.

Comment: I didn't want to urge you to write a complete solution (although I think that answers should be answers, and not vague hints - whether or not someone exploits an answer as the solution for his homework is in his own responsibility, but I see that others may have other opinions here). Storing the area in increasing and decreasing sort order may be one of the "neat tricks", this can indeed hel solving this in sub-O(n^2)-time

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution in Java. After calculating area Y, it first sorts the coordinates by X coordinates and then calculates the area of the rectangles by splitting the array into two halves at each X coordinate (with a special handling if two coordinates have the same X value). Then it does the same for the Y coordinates. The minimum rectangle area is the resulting X area.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Puzzle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] COORDINATES_1 = { { 4, 2 }, { 8, 10 }, { 1, 1 }, { 9, 12 }, { 14, 7 }, { 2, 3 } };
        int[][] COORDINATES_2 = { { 2, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 1 }, { 3, 3 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 3 }, { 5, 4 }, { 6, 4 } };
        int[][] COORDINATES_3 = { { 4, 2 } };

        solve(COORDINATES_1);
        solve(COORDINATES_2);
        solve(COORDINATES_3);
    }

    public static void solve(int[][] coordinates) {

        int size = coordinates.length;
        int y = calcMinRectArea(coordinates, 0, size);

        // sort by x coordinates
        Arrays.sort(coordinates, new Comparator<int[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
                return o1[0] - o2[0];
            }
        });

        int x = y;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (coordinates[i][0] == coordinates[i - 1][0])
                continue; // several coordinates with the same x coordinates
            x = Math.min(calcMinRectArea(coordinates, 0, i) + calcMinRectArea(coordinates, i, size - i), x);
        }

        // sort by y coordinates
        Arrays.sort(coordinates, new Comparator<int[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
                return o1[1] - o2[1];
            }
        });

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (coordinates[i][1] == coordinates[i - 1][1])
                continue; // several coordinates with the same y coordinates
            x = Math.min(calcMinRectArea(coordinates, 0, i) + calcMinRectArea(coordinates, i, size - i), x);
        }

        System.out.printf("Y = %d, X = %d, Y - X = %d\n", y, x, y - x);
    }

    private static int calcMinRectArea(int[][] coords, int start, int length) {

        if (length == 0)
            return 0;

        int minX = coords[start][0];
        int maxX = minX;
        int minY = coords[start][1];
        int maxY = minY;

        for (int i = start + 1; i < start + length; i++) {
            int x = coords[i][0];
            minX = Math.min(minX, x);
            maxX = Math.max(maxX, x);
            int y = coords[i][1];
            minY = Math.min(minY, y);
            maxY = Math.max(maxY, y);
        }

        return (maxX - minX) * (maxY - minY);
    }
}
```